# Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, xcode5

I have a library that is building and throwing this warning because ARC is turned off. However the project itself is ARC enabled. What are the implications of ignoring this warning?

```
- (void)dealloc {
   if (_framesetter) CFRelease(_framesetter);
   if (_highlightFramesetter) CFRelease(_highlightFramesetter);
}
```

Comment: Is this dealloc in the library or in the rest of the project?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the `dealloc` is in the library and the library has ARC turned off the dealloc must have `[super dealloc]` at the last line of the method body. Otherwise superclass will not be able to release its resources and free the object memory.

Answer (score 6):

In the library with ARC turned off, you can enable ARC for individual files by adding the `-fobjc-arc` compiler flag in the `Compile Sources` build phase. This will clear the warning.